# Does Swift support new data types and algebraic data types?

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift, and many other languages, there are built in data types as string, integer, etc...

For instances, in [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) one could use the keyword **data** to create your own data type.

> data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float
> Float

However, I am not sure if Swift has a similar way to do so, or whether it supports new data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type#Programming_languages_with_algebraic_data_types) lists Swift as one of the languages that support algebraic data types.

Just quoting Wikipedia isn't very convincing :D, so let's show your `Shape` type in Swift. This is achieved by enums with associated values.

```
enum Shape {
    case circle(Float, Float, Float)
    case rectangle(Float, Float, Float, Float)
}
```

`Circle 1 2 3` in Haskell would translate to `Shape.circle(1, 2, 3)` in Swift.

You can also add labels to those associated values:

```
enum Shape {
    case circle(centerX: Float, centerY: Float, radius: Float)
    case rectangle(x: Float, y: Float, width: Float, height: Float)
}
```

Learn more about enums with associated types [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148).

Another example would be the Haskell list type:

```
indirect enum List<T> {
    case `nil`
    case cons(T, List<T>)
}
```

Note that unlike Haskell, this isn't how lists are *actually* implemented in Swift.

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, that’s a really neat way to explain it.